# Is there a way to use macros in Excel online version(office 365)?

Tags: vba, excel-addins

I worked on excel macros for widows application to load data. I have created the add-in but now I have to use the same add-in in excel online version which is web based or is there any way to import the same add-in in online version or any way to write VBA programing for online version.

My requirement,

1.Call API and get data in Json format and pasted on the open sheet in the table format.

Tool using

1.Microsoft 365

Can you please help me with this.

Comment: You cannot use VBA in the web-based version of Excel.  You'd need to use javascript for any automation there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Office for the web does not support VBA. Apps in this version of office do not have the VBA IDE and will not load VBA project modules. They can open VBA enabled documents but the VBA components are hidden.  Microsoft's documentation goes as far as saying the web apps cannot create, edit, or run VBA.

At the minimum, Office for the web supports automation with Office Scripts, Power Automate, and Java Script.

Office Scripts is likely the easiest entry point to begin automating simple routine tasks. Users of the VBA macro recorder may even feel right at home using it with Excel's new macro recorder in the Automate tab of the ribbon.

Power Automate makes it relatively easy to extend automation across office apps and beyond the range of simple recorded macros.

JavaScript is also viable but do not expect the same experience you had with VBA. It requires additional configuration and overhead.

Modern assitive programs may help port VBA projects to Office for the web.

It should be noted that these solutions are marketed to businesses and Microsoft is pushing a business subscription requirement on a lot of their products.  You'll likely need a minimum of a business level office 365 subscription and may even need an add-on service.

An introduction to Office Scripts for the web version of Excel...

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/office-scripts-is-now-generally-available-in-excel-for-the-web/ba-p/2352548

Office Scripts API Reference...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/overview?view=office-scripts

Power Automate Actions Reference...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference

Excel's JavaScript API Reference (same link that @Tim Williams provided in comment to OP)...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview

Comment: what the heck..